# How do i number items in in Flask pagination object?

Tags: flask, pagination

Is there an in-built method in the Flask Pagination object that automatically numbers items in a sequence over multiple pages?

In simpler terms, lets say i have an SQL query that returns 25 items. The Per_page is set to 20. This gives me 2 pages. Is there a method that starts numbering articles in page 2 with the number 21?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem too and my solution was just some simple math.

```
{{ (page -1) * pagination_object.per_page + loop.index }}
```

where page was a passed variable to my template and was equal to the current page.

Comment: A suggestion:
`{{ (<pagination object>.page -1) * <pagination object>.per_page + <pagination object>.items.index(<item in the loop>) }}`